# How Do I Open Grid Text Files?

Tags: qgis, text

I've received wind speed data in grid text format and I have no idea how to open it in QGIS. Please go easy on the computer jargon, I'm no computer scientist.

[image]

Comment: drag and drop them into QGIS

Comment: well now I feel slightly silly!

Comment: These are in "ESRI ASCII Grid" format, a pretty common gridded data format from ESRI, who I think make some GIS software.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a drag and drop job...